# Visual C++ ShellExecute problems

Tags: c++, visual-c++, shellexecute

I am trying to use the shellexecute command to open a file in visual c++, I have included the following header files:

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

And the following is what I am using for my shellexecute:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("Open"), _T("C:\\Program Files\\My Prgram\\test1.pdf"), 
    NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

However I get the following error when I run this:

```
1>test1.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000011) "extern "C" struct HINSTANCE__ * __stdcall ShellExecuteW(struct HWND__ *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,int)" (?ShellExecuteW@@$$J224YGPAUHINSTANCE__@@PAUHWND__@@PB_W111H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall test1::Form1::button1_Click(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?button1_Click@Form1@test1@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
```

and also another almost identical error for unresolved external symbol rather than unresolved token. I have searched everywhere for this and have had many errors up to this point but I am really stuck now and would appreciate some help with this.

EDIT: Please note that this code is placed within a button clicked event.

Comment: Add shell32.lib to the linker's Additional Dependencies setting.  Your google foo is weak btw, just query "shellexecute lnk2028".

Comment: Thank you for your help, I apologize, I did not realize I could search errors like that, I will make sure I do it in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have checked the linker dependecy ? Try to check if there is shell32.lib and others.

You can also try to add

```
#pragma comment(lib "shell32.lib")
```